# Currently, is using google maps for android in China working?

Tags: android, google-maps

Currently developing an app including `google maps`, I'm willing to make it work for China as well.

I know the situation in China evolved a bit during the last years. So I would like to know: is it possible to use google maps for an android app in China?

If I attempt to use it as it is directly, the map remains blank, taking probably too long to load or being blocked by the chinese firewall. And my phone has the google services, which is not the case of many other phones.

However, a version of google maps exists in China. See this link: http://www.google.cn/maps?hl=en

So as a part of google is not blocked, would it be possible to load the data of the google maps API for android from the chinese server when the user himself is in China or doesn't have the google services or a VPN?

Comment: Refer to the FAQ here: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=en#china_ws_access

Comment: Thanks man but there is two things: First, this is using javascript and then, the google services are needed in my case. So google map can't be a solution for the chinese sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally gave up on google maps and change to GaoDe (amap).

First because Google maps need the googles services, which are not available on Chinese phones.

Then because if there is a way with JavaScript to get to the Chinese google map ( see the following link:  developers.google.com/maps/faq?hl=en#china_ws_access ), for android with java it is still not reliable.

Comment: Can We set the labels to english in AMAP/GaoDe Map

Answer (score 1):

Nearly all of the Google service are not working in China.
Most Chinese developer use Baidu or Gaode as the location provider.